# Need help with a book title - something like "Sting"

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic, childrens-novel

My son was telling me about a book that he read last year in class that had a picture of a bee on the cover, but where its abdomen is a syringe (with the needle in place of a stinger). It was kind of post-apocalyptic where people were being driven insane by bee stings or something. Somehow he's not even sure of the major plot points. :)

Anyway, we would like to figure out the title and author of this book. Apparently it is fairly recent, and a second book in the series was released this year.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect that the book is [Stung](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13517444-stung), by Bethany Wiggins.  The book is about people who are driven to violent madness by bio-engineered bee stings.  The cover art matches your description exactly.

[image: Cover of *Stung*]

It sounds like an interesting book; I'll have to check it out.

The second book in the series is titled [Cured](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17874904-cured), and was published in March.